# Isilon 'enabling_writes' gets stuck during failover

Tags: storage, isilon

I've been testing failover functionality on a new Isilon. Running OneFS 8.0.0 (A .0 release, but .1 is on the install queue).

Part of this is performing a failover operation, following a procedure on EMC's site - https://emcservice.force.com/CustomersPartners/kA2j0000000QXbrCAG
(First of all, we tried it using Superna Eyeglass, but could reproduce the problem using the documented procedure).

And on issuing `isi sync recovery allow-write policyname` our target transitions to `enabling_writes` and then seems to get stuck.

The only errors we've had pop up are:

```
786883 05/20 10:22    W    (policy name: failovertest target: localhost) SyncIQ encountered a filesystem error on source cluster. Error at source cluster on node [Isilon02-6]:  Operation failed while constructing list of lins changed between snapshots 36902 and 36288, Local error : No snapshots found between 36902 and 36288: No such file or directory
    from snapset_min_max (/b/mnt/src/isilon/lib/isi_migrate/config/../migr/summ_stf.c:391)
    from migr_start_changeset (/b/mnt/src/isilon/bin/isi_migrate/pworker/stf_based.c:1073)

786554 05/19 15:30    W    (policy name: failovertest target: localhost) SyncIQ failed to take a snapshot on source cluster. Failed to open and lock new snapid 36288: lock failed: marked for delete
```

Now, I appreciate this is probably something for the support team (and a case has been raised) however I'm posting this in the hopes anyone has seen similar, and can offer me pointers of where to look to troubleshoot. (I know my way around storage generally, but Isilons are something I've not really looked into before).

Comment: This sounds like, as you said, a .0 bug. Maybe add an answer here with whatever EMC replies with.

Comment: I have the same issue. Just stuck in that state forever.